# Embedded tomcat won't let my selenium/jbehave stories run

Tags: maven, selenium, jbehave, maven-tomcat-plugin, jbehave-plugin

I am trying for the **embedded tomcat to start before the integration tests** (mine use Selenium + JBehave) and **stop just afterwards**.

Here is how I tried to configure maven:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-tomcat</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-tomcat</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

However, Tomcat starts ok when I run `mvn integration-test` and it seems it won't let my stories run...

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution. It works with the following configuration:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-tomcat</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-tomcat</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Notice the added configuration element **which tells tomcat to fork**.